# Is there a way to format a variety of currencies on Python?

Tags: python, formatting, currency

I've got a Python web server (mod_python, if that makes any difference) that I want to start formatting some currency.  I've got two pieces of information when I format the currency - the value (as a number) and the currency (as the three-letter [ISO 4217 code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217)).  I can also retrieve the country (or even city) that the currency is being formatted in.  I can expect a large variety of currencies to be formatted - USD, CAD, JPY, GBP, EUR, etc.  Each request might be in a different currency.

I'm aware of [the locale module](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html), but it doesn't do what I want.  That module seems to be based around the computer's locale, so it doesn't work well for formatting any given currency.

Is there a way to do this in Python?  Or does anyone know of a good library that can solve this problem?

Comment: Formatting depends on a locale, not on the currency.  For example, EUR is used in several countries, which have several different formatting rules.

Comment: Hmm, good point.  I do have access to the country code as well.  I'll tack that on.

Answer (score 2):

For my internationalization needs, I almost invariably turn to [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/), a truly awesome package in both breadth and depth -- usually via [pyIcu](http://pyicu.osafoundation.org/), although in the past I've had to do some wrapping of my own when pyIcu hadn't yet wrapped some corner of ICU I needed (I'm not sure if they're currently wrapping all the currency-formatting operations you require).

The docs for PyIcu are [here](http://svn.osafoundation.org/pyicu/trunk/README), to be read "on top of" ICU's own docs [here](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/) -- in other words, the PyIcu-specific document is essentially a "phrasebook and dictionary" on how to "translate" ICU's own, C++ focused docs, into docs for PyIcu (and Python-focused ones;-).  Yeah, I know, not ideal -- not the only open-source package with imperfect docs I guess (me, I think that's an opportunity for some enterprising soul to write a "PyIcu, the missing manual" book, or the like;-).

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you could use regex or decimal formatting, but this module seems promising:

http://code.google.com/p/python-money/

> Python-money provides carefully
>   designed basic Python primitives for
>   working with money and currencies.
>
> The primary objectives of this module
>   is to aid in the development of
>   financial applications by increasing
>   testability and reusability, reducing
>   code duplication and reducing the risk
>   of defects occurring in the code.
>
> The module defines two basic Python
>   classes -- a Currency class and a
>   Money class. It also pre-defines all
>   the world's currencies, according to
>   the ISO 4217 standard. The classes
>   define some basic operations for
>   working with money, overriding
>   Python's addition, substraction,
>   multiplication, etc. in order to
>   account for working with money in
>   different currencies. They also define
>   currency-aware comparison operators.
>   To avoid floating point precision
>   errors in monetary calculations, the
>   module uses Python's Decimal type
>   exclusively.
>
> The design of the module is based on
>   the Money enterprise design pattern,
>   as described in Martin Fowler's
>   "Patterns of Enterprise Application
>   Architecture".